# Import FBX file doesn't appear

Tags: armature, import, motion-capture

I'm trying to import this [fbx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lirwty0xn8ksx8r/Test.fbx?dl=0) file in blender but the armature doesn't appear (no bones,...) Any idea please why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem with with my blender version, I've updated to the latest and it works perfect now! Many Thanks to @cegaton for the answer it helped me out figuring out the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The armature is there, it is huge.
To see it select the object on the outliner and on the 3D viewport press <kbd>Numpad Period</kbd>

[image]

You might need to adjust the clip start and end for the viewport...

Alternatively use the scale option on the importer to make the size more reasonable:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Tak Post an image that shows the settings for the fbx importer

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer made me think it may be caused by an issue in my version and it was :) I updated it and everything works fine now. Thanks heaps again :)