# how to scale imported .obj and .fbx

Tags: animation, rigging, 3d-view, import, .fbx

I received a 3D character model as a .obj file and as a .fbx file (with animation).

The imported .fbx file is about 1.5 Blender Units high, as expected.

The .obj file (containing the unrigged character) is 150 Blender Units high. When I try to scale the model down, I end up having issues that make it either impossible to navigate or hard to find. Even if I keep my eye on the model and zoom in, the viewport always seem to be looking past the model's shoulder, making rigging it at that size troublesome.

I don't have screenshots at the moment, so I'm hoping someone has run into a similar problem based on my description. Is there a way to import a .obj file so that it's small enough to fit on the usual Blender grid? Or after I scale it down, is there a way to reset the viewport to navigate around this object?

*If screenshots are needed, I'll see what I can do to upload. For now, here are the two files mentioned. Maybe these will help in recreating the problem I'm experiencing.

.obj file - https://ufile.io/wi90r
.fbx idle file - https://ufile.io/mif1u

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36302/obj-file-not-displayed-properly/36303#36303 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61374/import-fbx-file-doesnt-appear/61376#61376

Comment: This is an issue with your Camera Clipping Settings in the viewport (came across this post as I was trying to figure out my thing). Check this link for a more detailed description than I can give - but it's a simple fix, change your viewport settings and your model will all be there, even if you don't re scale it. https://www.thepolygonhub.com/blender-camera-viewport-clipping/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the different parts of the character you want to scale down.
2. [Snap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html) the [3D Cursor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html#usage) to the center of the grid by Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and selecting **Cursor to Center**.
3. We will use the cursor as a [pivot point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html). Use the [3D cursor as the pivot](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/3d_cursor.html) by pressing <kbd>.</kbd>.
4. Scale everything down by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> and entering the scale `0.01`, press enter to confirm. The objects should be scaled towards the center (0, 0, 0).
5. Apply rotation and scale by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and choosing *Rotation and Scale*.
6. [Align the 3D view](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/align.html#align-view-menu) pivot point to the current selection by pressing <kbd>NumpadPeriod</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

FBX natively works in cm, and to my understanding, the different programs always convert their units to cm, including Blender. However, it may also depend on the setting when exporting the FBX file from the other program.

When importing an OBJ in Blender, 1 unit in blender is equal to 1 unit from whichever program the model comes from. For example 1m in the obj is 1m in Blender when imported.

To modify the scale of your obj, after you have imported it, Blender should automatically select all the imported geometry, after which you should be able to scale it all by simply pressing <kbd>S</kbd> and then usually `0.1` (cm to m) or `0.01` (mm to m)